# React: How to unmute html video by custom button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project and came across a little issue:
So, i have a video tag:

```
<video muted autoPlay loop src={video}>
```

and i just want a single custom button/control to unmute and mute the video.
Am i right when i think of something using reactHooks and something like onClick={(handleChange => ??, or something like this:

```
    <button onClick={() => toggle(!mute)}>
        {mute ? 'Mute' : 'Unmute'}
    </button>
```

but i do not really know how to setup the mute function in order to control the video tag.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it, this is how:

```
const [muted, setMuted] = useState(true);
const handleToggleMute = () => setMuted(current => !current);
                
<button onClick={handleToggleMute} className="control">Unmute</button>
```